# How to initialise a Map<K, Map<K,V>> on a single line

Tags: java, dictionary

Is it possible to combine these two lines of code into one?

```
    allPeople.put("Me", new HashMap<String, String>());
    allPeople.get("Me").put("Name", "Surname");
```

Comment: Please edit your title to reflect your actual issue or question.

Comment: I wanted to put "How to initialise a Map<K, Map<K,V>> on a single line" but it has already been changed

Comment: @Red that looks like a reasonable title, go ahead and put it

Comment: @Red why do you think you should combine these into a single line?

Comment: You could avoid the `get` from `allPeople` by assigning `new` to a variable, putting `name, surname` to that variable, and then putting it to `allPeople`.  But assuming `allPeople` is a hash, that get would be efficient and I'd only optimize it if it's a scalability target (which is unlikely).  And it would then be three lines, albeit slightly more efficient.  Count operations, not lines!

Comment: @JeffLearman I first did it like that but at the start of my program I have to call a lot of lines like these by hand, so for the sake of readability I wanted to succeed to have a single line

Comment: @AndyTurner  ---

Comment: @Red unless you are trying to communicate "O" in Morse Code, I have no idea what you mean. And even if you are, I still don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal replacement of these two lines would be (in Java 8+):

```
allPeople.compute("Me", (k, v) -> new HashMap<>()).put("Name", "Surname");
```

or, in the style of [Bax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50221528/3788176), for pre-Java 9, you could use:

```
allPeople.put("Me", new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap("Name", "Surname")));
```

Comment: I think the use of `compute()` here is dangerous. If anyone sees this codes and replicates the line to add a second key/value pair, it will fail. Better to use [`computeIfAbsent("Me", k -> new HashMap<>())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: @Andreas but that's not the same. OP's code replaces whatever is there with an empty map. Your suggestion keeps whatever is there.

Comment: True. I still think you should cover the difference, and I think you should include the `Map.of()` variant for a full answer, with explanation of immutable maps vs making them mutable using `new HashMap<>(...)`. The question is too terse to know for sure whether OP (or other readers) need to add multiple key/value pairs.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Java 9 there is a JDK provided Map [factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V))

```
allPeople.put("Me", Map.of("Name", "Surname"));
```

Comment: In earlier versions, you could use `allPeople.put("Me", new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap("Name", "Surname")))`.

Comment: allPeople.put("Me", Map.of("Name", "Surname"));
  Does not seem to work but
  allPeople.put("Me", new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap("Name", "Surname")))
  works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @AndyTurner The pre-Java 9 equivalent of [`Map.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-) is just [`Collections.singletonMap(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap-K-V-). Both return an immutable map. `new HashMap<>(...)` would be needed for both of them, if you wanted a mutable map.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably represent a person as an object. That way you cannot call `get("someKey")` on a key that does not exist and your code blow up. That is the idea of object oriented programming. To encapsulate related data and functionality. Nested maps does a similar thing, but it is more error prone. For a language that does not support objects, that makes sense. But representing a person as an object allows you to better control the fields the mapping has, thus making your code more error-free.

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        this.name    = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

Then you create a map that maps names to people:

```
Map<String, Person> allPeople = new HashMap<>();

// Create an object that represents a person
Person me = new Person("name", "surname");

// Map the string "me" to the object me that represents me
allPeople.put("ME", me);
```

Comment: From an architectural point of view you're right. However, I guess he/she might just be looking for a technical "non-real-life" solution.

Comment: Yes but it's for a faculty project and I'm not allowed to do POO .. it doesn't make sense I know ..

Comment: @Matt or simply the fact that you can't always change things to the way you want them. Sometimes you've just got to work with the way it is.

Comment: @Red Yeah that doesn't make much sense haha. But as Andy said, sometimes you do have to work with what's available. Using Streams is a great tool. But if you are not familiar with functional programming and some of those fancy tools it make be harder to understand. So, I avoided a stream approach to illustrate (algorithmically) how to solve the problem. But using Java API is probably more error proof than code I could ever write.